# python crypto.sign not found, though it's in the module

Tags: python, pyopenssl

I'm trying to use some google api sample code, and it's not working.  Admittedly, I'm green at python, but I've boiled it down to this simple test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from OpenSSL import crypto

print crypto.sign('key', 'xyzzy', 'sha256')
```

which results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ot", line 5, in <module>
    print crypto.sign('key', 'xyzzy', 'sha256')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sign'
```

When I look at the openssl crypto module (`/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py`), it does, in fact, have "sign" defined:

```
def sign(self, pkey, digest):
    """
    Sign the certificate request using the supplied key and digest
```

so I'm very puzzled.  As near as I can tell, there are no other versions laying around

```
pip show pyopenssl
---
Name: pyOpenSSL
Version: 0.14
Location: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Requires: cryptography, six
```

Expanded output based on comments:

```
openssl file:
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.pyc

dir(crypto):
['Error', 'FILETYPE_ASN1', 'FILETYPE_PEM', 'FILETYPE_TEXT', 'NetscapeSPKI', 'NetscapeSPKIType', 'PKCS12', 'PKCS12Type', 'PKCS7Type', 'PKey', 'PKeyType', 'TYPE_DSA', 'TYPE_RSA', 'X509', 'X509Extension', 'X509ExtensionType', 'X509Name', 'X509NameType', 'X509Req', 'X509ReqType', 'X509StoreType', 'X509Type', 'X509_verify_cert_error_string', '_C_API', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_exception_from_error_queue', 'dump_certificate', 'dump_certificate_request', 'dump_privatekey', 'load_certificate', 'load_certificate_request', 'load_pkcs12', 'load_pkcs7_data', 'load_privatekey']

crypto file
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.so

crypto.sign:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ot", line 16, in <module>
print crypto.sign('key', 'xyzzy', 'sha256')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sign'
```

Comment: You may want to verify that the `OpenSSL` package you're importing from is the one you expect. Try `import OpenSSL`, then `print OpenSSL.__file__` to find its location. According to the docs, the `sign` method was added in OpenSSL 0.11, so if you are getting an older version when you import, it may not have the function.

Comment: What does `print dir(crypto)` output?

Comment: I've added output showing openssl.__file__, dir(crypto) and crypto.__file__.  If I read it right, somehow the crypto.so lib really is missing sign() and I should try rebuilding pyopenssl...

Answer (score 3):

For people not using openssl who have this problem (missing sign method) there is another solution.

Check the import section on the top of your code, you need to have this import :

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
```

and not the Crypto.Cipher implementation:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
```

This class doesn't have the sign method:
https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_Cipher-class.html

The Crypto.Signature PKCS1_v1_5 class has the sign method :https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_SigScheme-class.html

Answer (score 2):

I apparently had some conflicting installations - I removed a couple of yum python-crypto packages, then pip uninstalled openssl and there was still stuff in /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/ (including crypto.so), so I manually removed that directory and then pip installed pyopenssl and that solved the problem.  Thanks for the pointers...